# Ubuntu chmod permission not working for user

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I have a folder of logs in my environment that I want to download periodically to my local machine for parsing. I am trying to use `PSFTP` for this but I don't want to make it possible to log in as my root user in order to facilitate the process.

I have logged in via ssh and run the following commands:

1. `sudo -i` - Become root for session
2. `chmod -R 664 /path/to/logs` - I understand to be "Cur user R/W, Cur User Group R/W, Others R"
3. `exit` - Return to the logon user
4. `ls /path/to/` - Permission denied

I also tried `chmod o=r /path/to/logs` but have the same issue.

Is there something wrong with this or do I need to restart my session after any modification?

Output of the following commands:

1. `sudo ls -ld /path/to/logs` - "dr--r--r-- 2 root root 4096 Apr 29 16:36 /path/to/logs"
2. `sudo ls -id /path/to/logs` - "264178 /path/to/logs"
3. `sudo ls -ld /path/to/logs/single-log` - "-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 583613 Apr 29 16:41 /path/to/logs/single.log"
4. `sudo ls -id /path/to/logs/single-log` - "299354 /path/to/single.log"

Comment: Use the commands `sudo ls -ld /path/to/logs`; `sudo ls -ld /path/to/logs/single-log` to see the owner/group/perms of the directory and a file in there. Use `id` to see the current user/group. Add that to your question so it's easier for us to diagnose.

Comment: Edit: put it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've removed the `x` bit from the directories, which needs to be set in order for users to read the directory. Try this

```
sudo su -i
cd /path/to/logs
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod u+x,g+x,o-x
find . -print0 | xargs -0 chmod u+r,g+r,o-r
```

The first `find` command will restore the `x` bit to the directory for user and group.

The second `find` command adds read access to files and directories for user and group.

Comment: Still getting permission denied from the other user after I exit the sudo session running  `ls /path/to/logs`

Comment: I should add the path is currently in the root user's directory, which may cause additional complications. I'm trying to fix this in the next deploy.

Comment: Every directory in the tree needs to be `+rx`. For example, if `/path/to` is `700` then it doesn't matter what `/path/to/logs` is. Changing that for the root user's directory is not generally a good idea.

Comment: I removed the existing api and reinstalled it to /srv/{project} and ran the same commands and it worked easily. Thanks!